# Collect primitive array values into a collection of type Map

Tags: java, collections, java-stream, primitive, boxing

How can I convert an array of primitive `int`, `long`, or `double` values into a collection of type `Map`?

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class PrimitiveStreamCollection {
    private static final String[] words = {
        "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four",
        "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"
    };
    
    private static final int[] numbers = { 8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9 };

    public static Map<Integer, String> collect(int[] values) {
        return // Collect the array of values into a Map<Integer, String>
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Integer, String> map = collect(numbers);
        System.out.println(map);
        // {0=zero, 3=three, 5=five, 6=six, 7=seven, 8=eight, 9=nine}
    }
}
```

Comment: The title and question are bit underwhelming. Into a collection of _what_? A collection of type `Map` of _what_? Please edit to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

In order to convert an array of primitive values to a collection; the values need to either be `boxed` into corresponding object types, or the `collect` method for the primitive stream needs to be called.

### Boxing

Here are the 8 primitive types and their corresponding wrapper classes:

- `bool` → `Boolean`
- `byte` → `Byte`
- `char` → `Character`
- `double` → `Double`
- `float` → `Float`
- `int` → `Integer`
- `long` → `Long`
- `short` → `Short`

> *See also*: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

In the code below, the `int[]` is transformed into an `IntStream` which is then boxed into a `Stream<Integer>` and collected with the `Collectors.toMap` collector.

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class PrimitiveStreamCollection {
    private static final String[] words = {
        "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four",
        "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"
    };

    private static final int[] numbers = { 8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9 };

    public static Map<Integer, String> collectBoxed(int[] values) {
        return Arrays.stream(values)
            .boxed()
            .collect(
                Collectors.toMap(
                    Function.identity(),
                    value -> words[value]));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Integer, String> boxedMap = collectBoxed(numbers);
        System.out.println(boxedMap);
    }
}
```

### Primitive streams

The `Arrays.stream` method has been overridden to accept only arrays of `double`, `int`, and `long`.

- `double[]` → `DoubleStream`
- `int[]` → `IntStream`
- `long[]` → `LongStream`

In the code below, the `collect` method is called directly on the primitive stream object. It takes three arguments:

- `supplier` - in this case a `HashMap<Integer, String>`
- `accumulator` - how to apply the iteree to the supplier
- `combiner` - how multiple values are combined

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class PrimitiveStreamCollection {
    private static final String[] words = {
        "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four",
        "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"
    };

    private static final int[] numbers = { 8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9 };

    public static Map<Integer, String> collectUnboxed(int[] values) {
        return Arrays.stream(values)
            .collect(
                HashMap::new,
                (acc, value) -> acc.put(value, words[value]),
                HashMap::putAll);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Integer, String> unboxedMap = collectUnboxed(numbers);
        System.out.println(unboxedMap);
    }
}
```